# javascript Cannot read property 'children' of null whilte

Tags: javascript, html, css, haml

I have this snippet code at [codepen](https://codepen.io/stevemckinney/pen/KVewMV) and it's working perfectl, but 
When trying copy it to my site it's show this error :

```
(index):257 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
    at (index):257
(anonymous) @ (index):257
```

which means this line in my site :

```
var count = items.children.length;
```

I just copy compiled html, css and js same it's without any edit, May I know why this happen ?

Comment: What does `items` return? :)

Comment: @Ionut https://codepen.io/stevemckinney/pen/KVewMV

Comment: @dan, I meant on your website...not on the codepen.

Comment: The error says that `items` is `null`. There's no information in your question that tells us why you think `items` should be anything other than `null`.

Comment: Did u paste the script at bottom

Comment: @Rajesh sorry, the the brackets by mistake

Comment: @dan make sure you have all the correct tags added. It will take question right people

Comment: my code is same snippet code exactly @Quentin

Comment: @dan — It can't be. If that was all of your code then you should get a reference error since you are trying to read `items` without ever assigning a value to it.

Comment: @dan not sure about `haml` but try `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ // your code });`

Answer (score 2):

You probably have the Javascript code in your `<head></head>` tag.

There the `DOM` is — not — ready yet.

Try copying your `<script>code</script>` right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Did you press `STRG + SHIFT + R`. Because perhaps it is in the cache.

Comment: You are genius. Thank you